# SpriteKit: Checking for a sprite of certain coordinates not functioning as expected

Tags: objective-c, macos, coordinates, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit game for Mac I am developing, and I need to be able to check when certain sprite nodes are below a certain Y axis. I am using this code currently:

```
-(void) hitOrMiss {
    double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        if (orb.position.y < 80) {
            NSLog(@"Miss!");
            [orb removeFromParent];
        }
        [self hitOrMiss];
    });
}
```

It is meant to run a continuous loop every 0.1 seconds, and check for orbs below a y position of 80. When I use this method in my program, often it does not acknowledge orbs that are below 80, and sometimes Logs the same orb multiple times before removing it from the parent. I have multiple orbs that are moving across the screen, is this the reason why it is not functioning as I expected it to consistently?

Thank you, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using `SKAction` to accomplish this:

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
SKAction *yCheckAction = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:delayInSeconds], [SKAction runBlock:^{
        if (orb.position.y < 80) {
            NSLog(@"Miss!");
            [orb removeFromParent];
        }
    }]]];
[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:yCheckAction]];
```

If you need to enumerate through every single orb, you can set the `orb.name` property to a string (say, @"orb"), then use that string in the following method:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"orb" usingBlock:^(SKNode *orb, BOOL *stop) {
    // code to execute on every orb here
}];
```

Yet, actions can be quite heavy, so if you don't have to have the 0.1 second delay, it's probably best to put it in the update method, as the other tip here suggests. So:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"orb" usingBlock:^(SKNode *orb, BOOL *stop) {
        if (orb.position.y < 80) {
            NSLog(@"Miss!");
            [orb removeFromParent];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in the update method of the SKScene. SpriteKit games normally run at 60 frames per second, you can iterate through all the orb and check if they are under 80 on the y axis. Doing it in actions or GCD is a bit like shooting elephants by stuffing them into your gun and over your bullet with a giant eledozer (slang for elephant dozer, not patented, surprisingly).